# 500 internal server error while authenticating Microsoft graph

Tags: flask-oauthlib

I am using python and flask for making web pages. I am trying to authenticate Microsoft graph but its giving an error. Please see the picture below:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `debug` mode to see debug information.

1. Flask > 1.0, use `FLASK_ENV=development`.
2. Flask < 1.0, use `FLASK_DEBUG=1`.

---

Flask-OAuthlib itself doesn't support proxy. You can try https://github.com/lepture/authlib it uses requests for OAuth client. Requests support proxy http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: Actually, I am behind a proxy. No authentication is going through which has python code it. I tried authenticating to Microsoft graph using angularJS and its working fine. I don't how to to get this python version working in my company

Comment: @AlyZayn Flask-OAuthlib itself doesn't support proxy. You can try https://github.com/lepture/authlib it uses requests for OAuth client. Requests support proxy http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies